# Anchor commands not running in VScode

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, anchor-solana, solana-cli

I have installed Rust, Solana cli, and anchor cli. Anchor commands are working fine in the terminal but not in the project workspace. I'm new to rust, my guess is it should be initialized first then have to use anchor commands. Would really appreciate some resources that provide step-by-step instruction since I'm not able to find good resources yet.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: try using avm to install anchor and then try it